# Display the x-axis of the range bar chart at the top instead of bottom

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular6, kendo-chart

I want to move x-axis of range bar chart to the top using Kendo chart for angular 2.

[image: sample chart image]

I am using [Range Bar](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/series-types/range-bar/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the axisCrossingValue on the value axis to determine where the category axis crosses it.  https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/ValueAxis/#toc-axiscrossingvalue

Just set the crossing value to a high index, like 1000 and it will be placed at the top:

```
  <kendo-chart-value-axis>
      <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [axisCrossingValue]=1000>
      </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-value-axis>
```